# Removing white space and line breaks from source using PHP

Tags: php, html, regex

I have the following function that I use in a PHP application to remove white space and line breaks from the source of a page.

It's based on some examples I have read on Stack Overflow, with some amends to handle JS and HTML comments. **Note: I've not used an exisiting library because I wanted something simple without all the additional features that others include and with this code I have fine-grained control over what is stripped and what is not.**

```
protected function MinifyHTML($str) {

    $str = preg_replace("/(?<!\S)\/\/\s*[^\r\n]*/", "", $str); // strip JS/CSS comments
    $str = preg_replace("/<!--(.*)-->/Uis", "", $str); // strip HTML comments

    $protected_parts = array('<pre>,</pre>','<textarea>,</textarea>','<,>');
    $extracted_values = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($protected_parts as $part) {
        $finished = false;
        $search_offset = $first_offset = 0;
        $end_offset = 1;
        $startend = explode(',', $part);
        if (count($startend) === 1) $startend[1] = $startend[0];
        $len0 = strlen($startend[0]); $len1 = strlen($startend[1]);
        while ($finished === false) {
            $first_offset = strpos($str, $startend[0], $search_offset);

            if ($first_offset === false) $finished = true;
            else {
                $search_offset = strpos($str, $startend[1], $first_offset + $len0);
                $extracted_values[$i] = substr($str, $first_offset + $len0, $search_offset - $first_offset - $len0);
                $str = substr($str, 0, $first_offset + $len0).'$$#'.$i.'$$'.substr($str, $search_offset);
                $search_offset += $len1 + strlen((string)$i) + 5 - strlen($extracted_values[$i]);
                ++$i;
            }
        }
    }

    $str = preg_replace("/\s/", " ", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\s{2,}/", " ", $str);
    $replace = array('> <'=>'><', ' >'=>'>','< '=>'<','</ '=>'</');
    $str = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $str);

    for ($d = 0; $d < $i; ++$d)
        $str = str_replace('$$#'.$d.'$$', $extracted_values[$d], $str);

    return $str;

}
```

However if I get a scenario like:

```
<a href="">Link</a> <a href="">Link</a>
```

It will remove that space between the two anchor tags.

I've added `'</a> <a'` to my `$protected_parts` in an attempt to stop this, but it still strips out the space between them. So I end up with `<a href="">Link</a><a href="">Link</a>` in the source which isn't what I want.

The same also happens with:

```
<p>This is <span class="">some</span> <span class="">styled</span> text.</p>
```

Also it seems the protected_parts arn't working as my textareas are being minified too so all the content inside them is compressed down into one line...

Any ideas on the fixes? I've also not been able to find alternatives to use instead that don't implement caching, gzipping and other features I don't want. I purely want a simple solution that strips spaces, line breaks and comments and that's it.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What are you expecting to gain?  Whitespace in your source is a GOOD thing for your readability in working on display layer rpoblems. Eliminating whitespace typically has miniscule impact on page load times due to compression typically in place between browser and server.  You are likely to slow down your application and/or cause much higher memory overhead on your server by storing your entire output in memory and then trying to run a bunch of regex operations on it.

Comment: That is not to mention that if you TRULY wanted to do this, you should be using a DOM Parser.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATED 2014/02/25 (late):

Here's another workaround. Instead of touching `$protected_parts` I'm just adding another replace operation at the end that adds a space after every `</a>` -- again a workaround, but this shouldn't screw up any of your original operability, and the penalty this time is only one space character after every anchor tag, not bad. Here it is: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5qj-13z

## UPDATED 2014/02/25:

<strike>I added `'</a> '`  to `$protected_parts` and it does not strip the space.  I threw it into phpfiddle over here, http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/dms-cud. This is only a workaround for a few lines of synethetic-emulated HTML... I'm not sure what kind of organic code you're running through your function. Obviously this workaround is not a universal fix either.</strike>

## Original

<strike>I added `'</a>',' <a ',`  to `$protected_parts` and it does not strip the space.  I threw it into phpfiddle over [here, http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ztz-5hf](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/ztz-5hf).</strike>

Your function is scary to me, but I like some of the basic functionality, like stripping HTML, JS and CSS comments. I'd still recommend using an apache extension or library. Using other people's open source code is the most powerful witchcraft a programmer can yield. :)

Comment: Adding that destroyed everything else though and added ### and $$$# to links etc :P

Comment: Well firstly I'd echo Mike Brant's comment. But I've updated my answer with another workaround for your bug. I tested this one with more HTML than last time. Have you found a full fix? If not, let me know and I can try to implement a library function.

Comment: Hey thanks for the second attempt. Still breaking the site, but not as aggressive as before. I'll try and post some sample HTML for you to compare against if you like? Thanks again for your help so far.

Comment: What about doing that replace ONLY if two anchors are next to each other? Is that possible.

Comment: That sounds like it would solve it: `$replace = array ('</a><a' => '</a> <a'); $str = str_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $str);` ----> http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/r8r-mtj

Comment: Cool, I'll give that a try later. I guess I'll need to do that for every inline element to prevent it. e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements

Comment: Have a look at [this plugin](https://github.com/stevenvachon/html-minify/blob/master/html-minify.php), it's the standalone version of  a wordpress plugin by the same author. Implementation might take less time than refactoring your code.